# Is there any useful metadata inside shared objects, and if so, how do I extract it?

Tags: dynamic-linking

I have a file called `mod_dav_svn.so`. I would like to find out if this is a custom version of the file or a standard one.

I have tried searching Google for the md5sum of the file, but nothing has turned up, suggesting it is a custom compilation.

Is there a way to extract any metadata from this file, such as compilation time/options/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your distro's package manager and verify the package to see if the file is original. For example in my rpm based distro I can do the following:

```
 # Find the full path to the file
 $ locate mod_dav_svn.so
 /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so

 # Find out what package it belongs to
 $ rpm -qf /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so
 apache-mod_dav_svn-1.6.16-1.i686

 # Verify that package to make sure the file hasn't been tampered with
 $ rpm -vV apache-mod_dav_svn
 ........     /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_svn.so
```

The dots indicate that all tests show normal for that file. If it had been changed it might have indicated a checksum mismatch, a date change, a size change, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is `file mod_dav_svn.so` to see what architecture it's for, and `ldd mod_dav_svn.so` to see what libraries (and versions) it's linked against.

You can search for printable strings with [strings](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/strings.html) (`strings mod_dav_svn.so`).

You can display a lot of information in <strike>readable</strike> text form with [objdump](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/binutils/objdump.html). Try inspecting the file with `objdump -s mod_dav_svn.so | less`, the compiler might have left a clue somewhere.